# Clear all lines in a range in c

Tags: c

I need to clear all lines between StartLine and ScreenHight in c, But i get the compiler error:
`warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]`

Code:

```
void clearScreen(int startLine, int screenHight)
{
    for (int i=startLine; i<screenHight - 1; ++i)
    {
        printf("\x1b[",i,";1H\33[2K");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[The first argument of `printf` is a format string.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) Your format string `"\x1b["` does not have any format specifiers, so `printf` won't expect any of the other arguments you provided. Thus, it will only print the format string.

To specify the other two arguments, use `%d` (to print the integer `i`) and `%s` (to print the string `";1H\33[2K"`):

```
printf("\x1b[%d%s",i,";1H\33[2K");
```

Comment: Thank you very much, im very new to c this helped me alot :)

Comment: Consider using `printf("\x1b[%d;1H\33[2K", i);`

Answer (score 0):

You were trying to contcatenate a string for using as a paremeter in the
`printf` call. But that is not how you craete a string in `c`.
Use another way to build your string parameter (e.g. `sprintf`)    and
then use that string as a parameter to the `printf` call.